# Table positioning forces weird spacing between paragraphs

Tags: floats, positioning

I have quite a long table that almost fits one page. The table needs to be placed at the end of the section. The next section begins with a short paragraph so Latex always place the table next to that last paragraph. 
I used the `float` package to force the table positioning but now the paragraphs on the page before the table are stretched out on the whole page.

How can I set the paragraphs to have a normal spacing between them and make it so that all the remaining space is just at the end of the page?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{the last paragraph}
This is some text that makes up the last paragraph of this section.

\begin{table}[H]
\captionsetup{position=top, skip=0.5ex}
\caption{Caption of the table}
\label{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
Data & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
More data & 2 & 1 & 0 &  4 \\
Also data & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\section{the next section}
A very short parapgraph that fits on one page with the table.    
\end{document}
```

Comment: A compilable MWE (currently, the documentclass is missing)  that reproduces the issue you describe would be helpful. Without it, I guess that adding `\raggedbottom` to the preamble might solve your problem.

Comment: Why are you using `H` in the first place? Generally it is better to learn use floats properly and not rely on figures or tables not being right *HERE*.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying, I am sorry. I need my table to be at the end of the section for clearity. I tried just using `h` or `h!` but that was not working.

Comment: Try letting the table float, with option `[!h]`  and adding `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` to your preamble.

Comment: Report use \flusbottom, try changing to \raggedbuttom, and the whitespace will be at the bottom of the page. If you use footnotes, you should also load the package footmisc with the option bottom, to force the footnotes to the bottom of the page. Or you may consider changing to scrrprt.

Comment: You problem is not very clear to me, since your code example does not exhibit any of the behavior you describe. Using `[H]` (or even one of the `[h]` variants) is generally not a very good idea. If you don't want your table to float, don't put it into a `table` environment! As far as I can guess your situation, I think it would be best to just remove `[H]` and reference the table by number (using `\ref`). If you want the next section to start on a new page, use `\clearpage`. Otherwise, please provide an MWE that actually illustrates your problem.